# Is there a largest o-minimal structure all of whose definable functions are analytic?

Tags: model-theory, analytic-functions, o-minimal

In the paper "[Quasianalytic Denjoy-Carleman classes and o-minimality](https://doi.org/10.1090/S0894-0347-03-00427-2)" by J.-P. Rolin, P. Speissegger and A. J. Wilkie, it is proven that there is no largest o-minimal structure on the real numbers. The construction of two incompatible structures involves some non-analytic functions, and so seems rather artificial. Is the following more refined question open:

> Does there exist a largest o-minimal structure such that all definable functions in that structure are piecewise analytic?

As all restricted analytic functions are known to generate an o-minimal structure, one can even ask a more general question:

> Let $\mathcal{S}$ and $\mathcal{S}'$ be two o-minimal sturctures on the same densely ordered set $(M, <)$. We say that $\mathcal{S}$ and $\mathcal{S}'$ *have the same restricted fragment* if a bounded subset $A \subseteq M^n$ is definable in $\mathcal{S}$ if and only if it is definable in $\mathcal{S}'$. Is it true that for any o-minimal structure there exists a largest o-minimal structure on the same that having the same restricted fragment?

Answer (score 3):

About your first question, I think the answer is no. There is an example in Rolin Sanz Schafke ``*quasi-analytic solutions of analytic ODE and o-minimal structures*" that gives two (actually, infinity many pairs of) o-minimal structures which both admit analytic cell decomposition (so any definable function there is piecewise analytic) but which are incompatible from the o-minimal point of view (the structure generated by all sets definable in the one and the other is not o-minimal anymore).